# How to use custom event parameters for checkbox click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

From jQuery's doc, it seems I should be able to pass custom parameters to the checkbox click handler using [`$.fn.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). However, I can't seem to get this working.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"/>        <span></span>
<hr/>
<input type="text"/>            <span></span>
<hr/>
<button>foo</button>            <span></span>
```

JS:

```
$('input, button').click(function(e, arg1) {
    console.log(arguments);
    $(this).next().text('arg1: ' + arg1);
});
$('input, button').triggerHandler('click', ['passed in', 'unused arg']);
```

The text input and the button clearly works, but the checkbox doesn't work.

Using jQuery 1.10.2. Tested with Firefox 28, Chrome 34.

#### EDIT:

Just tried changing `trigger` to `triggerHandler` and it seems to fix the checkbox while breaking the other two.

http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/1/

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the behavior so strange?

Comment: did you read the api for triggerHandler? it clearly isn't what you want. `While .trigger() will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, .triggerHandler() only affects the first matched element.` by even including that you attempted it and including it in your question just complicates the question.

Comment: If you need a custom parameter why not use .data() to that?

Comment: @Freak_Droid i don't think that's the question. the behavior of .trigger isn't working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/3/ it doesn't pass the argument for the checkbox, but it does for the rest.

Comment: The fact that it works for .triggerHandler on the checkbox but not trigger leads me to believe the problem is due to a special case for handling click events on checkboxes. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: @KevinB Ah thanks for pointing it out; I missed that part. What I really wanted was `.trigger` though (since I want the native event to be triggered). I just skimmed the `.triggerHandler` doc and tried it in desperation.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a special case for checkboxes that when you trigger the click event, the native click event is fired to cause the state to change. Because of this, jquery is unable to pass the extra event parameter. Whether or not this is a bug or intended, i don't know.

The solution is to use `triggerHandler` and a loop to get by the `.first()` that gets applied by `triggerHandler`. `triggerHandler` works because it doesn't invoke the native click event (it doesn't need to change the state since you're just triggering the *handler*)

```
$('input, button').click(function(e, arg1) {
    console.log(arguments);
    $(this).next().text('arg1: ' + arg1);
});
$('input, button').each(function(){
    $(this).triggerHandler('click', ['passed in', 'unused arg']);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/4/

Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.3/src/event.js#L557

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, though it doesn't exactly answer my original question. I'm actually not trying to trigger multiple elements -- that was just a demonstration to show the problem with checkboxes. I think I'm going to try using triggerHandler on the checkbox, then manually setting the check using `.prop('checked', state)` to emulate the native event

Comment: I think that would be the best compromise. Could even do `this.checked = !this.checked` to make it an easy toggle.

Comment: Ah using `this` wouldn't work with the native click event: http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/6/. Had to call it from the same place as the `triggerHandler`: http://jsfiddle.net/2t6y7/7/. Thanks for the idea of using the `.checked` directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [bug](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13353) that was [fixed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4139) in jQuery [release 3.4.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/).